# How could i start an ETF or Mutual fund?

Tags: investing, stock-markets, etf, mutual-funds

I want to start a mutual fund and an etf. How would i go about doing this? i would want it to be publicly traded on the market. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: To start an ETF, you'll need a lot of money and a lot of market knowledge.   [Read this](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/040115/how-create-your-very-own-etf.asp) and then contact the management companies listed in order to get a first hand idea of the requirements.

Comment: Why would anyone invest with you?

Comment: well, i was thinking i would start a clean energy etf, but i’m not sure. i guess i would have to gain a reputation of high returns first...

Answer (score 5):

How to start a mutual fund:

1. Develop a strategy that outperforms an index *of similar risk level*.
   or
   1a) Pick an index to replicate (meaning you have to buy the constituent list form the index provider)
2. Get investors to give you millions of dollars to buy the constituent stocks
3. Profit (by charging a small percentage of the NAV of the fund).

How to start an ETF:

1. Complete steps 1-3 above
2. Partner with a large investment bank to be an *authorized participant* that will create/destroy new units as people buy and sell the ETF. They also buy/sell constituents of the fund to keep the NAV in line with the ETF market price.

Remember that the fund does not profit when the price of the constituent shares goes up - it profits by *charging a fee to participants*. So the fee you charge needs to be enough to cover your expenses but not so much that your strategy needs to beat the benchmark by more than that amount.  So if you charge a 1% fee, you need to beat your benchmark by 1%. That's why index trackers charge very low fees-  they are just tracking the index, so there's no active management fees, and investors only pay the fee to buy a fund that they can't replicate through the constituents, since retail investors can't practically buy all components of the S&P 500 with any volume.

***DISCLAIMER:***

I'm certain I'm leaving out an incredible amount of detail involving lawyers, regulations, etc.; my point was to somewhat tongue-in-cheek illustrate that creating a mutual fund requires both a solid investment strategy and millions of dollars from other people.